# Multiclass classification using Keras ValueError: Error when checking target:

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a model to predict the damage of house. I am using Keras for this.

There are 5 values to be predicted in column 'damage_grade' between 1 to 5. The Higher the number, the more damage a house can get.

Also I would like to mention I am beginner in Keras and it is my first model in Keras. I am trying to do it by taking help from [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/).

My code is:

```
X_train = rtrain_df.drop("damage_grade", axis=1) 
Y_train = rtrain_df["damage_grade"] 
X_test = rtest_df.drop("building_id", axis=1).copy() 
X_train.shape, Y_train.shape, X_test.shape

import keras 
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation 
from keras.optimizers import SGD

model = Sequential() 
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=46)) #there are 46 feature in my dataset to be trained 
model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=128)
```

When trying to fit the model it gives the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_6 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)

There are around 600 000 records to be trained

Comment: If the house damage, which you are trying to predict, is one single number then you only need to have a Dense layer with a single unit as the last layer: `model.add(Dense(1))`. Otherwise, please add the information about the shape and values of `Y_train` to your post.

Comment: Actually there are 5 values to be predicted between 1 to 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code:

- You've given 10 in the last Dense layer. It must be equal to the number of values to be predicted i.e. 5.
- You must convert your Y_train into a categorical array having 5 categorical features ('damage_grade' from 0 to 4).

Below is the corrected code:

```
X_train = rtrain_df.drop("damage_grade", axis=1) 
Y_train = rtrain_df["damage_grade"] 
X_test = rtest_df.drop("building_id", axis=1).copy() 
X_train.shape, Y_train.shape, X_test.shape

import keras 
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation 
from keras.optimizers import SGD

from keras.utils import np_utils
Y_train_cat = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train) # converts into 5 categorical features

model = Sequential() 
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=46))
model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax')) 

# last Dense layer is the output layer that'll produce the probabilities for the 5 
# outputs

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train_cat, epochs=20, batch_size=128)

import numpy as np

predictions = model.predict(X_test)
result = np.argmax(predictions,axis=1) # sets the output with max probability to 1
```

Comment: Thanks.
But when  I change Y_train to Y_train_cat  then last dense layer has probabilities of 6 output .
means
    ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_6 to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1,)
       But actually there are only 5 values to be predicted.